# read_sql: value error invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'11+00'?

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I have a database where I made columns using:

```
c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {} '
              '(timestamp timestamp, '
              'symbol TEXT, '
              'last_price REAL, '
              'bid_qty INT, '
              'bid REAL, '
              'ask REAL, '
              'ask_qty INT)'.format(symbol))
```

When I try to use `pandas.read_sql' with the following statement:

```
select_statement = 'select * from ' + key + ' order by timestamp DESC limit 80000'
m1df = pd.read_sql(select_statement, conn)
```

I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
> File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 489, in read_sql
> chunksize=chunksize,
> File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1740, in read_query
> data = self._fetchall_as_list(cursor)
> File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1753, in _fetchall_as_list
> result = cur.fetchall()
> File "/usr/lib/python3.6/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 70, in convert_timestamp
> hours, minutes, seconds = map(int, timepart_full[0].split(b":"))
> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'11+00'

When I try:

```
select_statement = 'select * from ' + key + ' DESC limit 80000'
m1df = pd.read_sql(select_statement, conn)
```

There is no error. I assume the selected rows don't have the timezone "+00" issue.

I read up on the issue but haven't been able to find a way around it.

Comment: The error is still there if you use `pd.read_sql(..., parse_dates={"date_column": {"errors": "ignore"}})`?

Comment: @Corralien yes same error. I have used this database before and encountering this error for the first time.

Comment: Again, please refrain from adding "TIA" and other chatty material to your posts.